# superimpose several ggplot to make a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I am trying to make a map using R but I have some problems. The datas I have are shapefiles. I used ggplot to visualise them with this code :

```
ggplot(farmscot)+geom_sf()
ggplot(scotland)+geom_sf()
ggplot(river)+geom_sf()
```

and it gives me different graphs like this:

[image]
[image]

but I need them to be superimpose to make the map. How can I do please?

When I try to add them together R says I can't add ggplots together
Would really appreciate some help and advice, Thank you in advance

Comment: Try with `ggplot() + geom_sf(data = farmscot) + geom_sf(data = scotland) + ...`, i.e. you could have multiple layers in ggplot2 and each could have its own data.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked ! with this code ggplot(farmscot) + geom_sf(aes(fill = Capacity_M)), I color coded the farms  , can I still do it with the farms being a geom and not directly in the ggplot ? Because when I add it it the code I get an error

Comment: Sure. That should work or could be made work. :D